# Breeze entity Key not set at creation time

Tags: c#, javascript, breeze, durandal-2.0

I have the following JS script that creates a product object:

```
var entityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery,
        manager = configureBreezeManager();
function configureBreezeManager() {
    breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
    return new breeze.EntityManager(config.remoteServiceName);;
}
...
var createProduct = function () {
    var product = manager.createEntity('Product', { name: '', description: ''});
    return product;
};
```

and the server back end:

```
public class Product{
    int ProductId{get;set;}
    String Name{get;set;}
    String Description{get;set;}
}
```

The problem is that the `product`'s key is always -1 when created. Trying to a product locally by id (-1) returns an empty result.

How can I create an entity and be able to get it back when needed (without first saving the entity to the server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand the question. But when you call *EntityManager.createEntity* the entity is created and added to the EntityManager's cache.

This means that when you call *EntityManager.getEntities* you will find the entity, or when you run a local cache query via *EntityManager.executeQueryLocally* or query with a FetchStrategy of FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache you will also find the entity.

The entity will not appear on the server until you perform a save at which time the local entity's will change from a temporary key to a permanent one.  For more see the "Temporary Key Generation" topic on this page: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities

Comment: Oh my bad! I though a Key of -1 is invalid but apparently it is perfectly valid until the entity is saved back to the server!